# How to prevent received data from being messy by using promises and then() inside for loop

Tags: javascript, express, for-loop, asynchronous, promise

How can i manage to run this :

```
for(let i=0; i<3; i++){
   setTimeout(function() {console.log("A")}, 500);
}

console.log('B');
```

and make it synchronous to get the following output :

```
AAAB
```

I oversimplified the situation here, but in my code, I have a for loop that iterates 3 times. Inside it, I first make an external API request which body's returned using a promise. I use then(). to run the suite of the loop's content. 
**BUT** after the loop, I want to refresh the page.
The issue is that the page refreshes before the loop has finished :

```
// API call
function call(src,dest) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve,reject) {
        request('https://api.skypicker.com/flights?flyFrom='+src+'&to='+dest+'&dateFrom='+date+'&dateTo='+nextDate+'&partner=picky', function (err, res, body) {
            if (!err && res.statusCode === 200) {
                resolve(body);
            } else {
                reject(err);
            }
        });
    })
}
```

**Here is the for loop:**

```
if (arr.length > 0 && arr[0]!==""){
            for (let k = 0; k < arr.length ; k++){
                    let flight = call(dataPays.pays,arr[k]);
                    flight.then(function (result) {
                        info.dest = result;
                    }).catch(function (error) {
                        console.log("ERROR :" + error );
                    }).then(function () {
                        let object = JSON.parse(info.dest);
                        let myArray = object.data;
                        dataPays.dest[count]=dataPays.pays + " --> " + arr[k]+ ": ";
                        count++;
                        //start
                        for (let j = 0; j < myArray.length ; j++){
                            if (!valueExists(checker,object.data[j]["flyTo"])){
                                let string = "dest_" + j;
                                dataPays.dest[count]="  from "+object.data[j]["flyFrom"] + "  to  " +object.data[j]["flyTo"] + "  " + object.data[j]["price"]+ "€  " ;
                                checker[string] = object.data[j]["flyTo"];
                                count++;
                            }
                        }
                    }).then(function () {
                        console.log("after then  " + k + "  -- " );
                        if (k === arr.length-1){                
                            console.log("refreshing");
                            res.redirect(req.get('referer'));                   
                        }
                    })
            }
    }
```

Here, We can see that I've tried to fix the issue by using the value of k to refresh the page at the last iteration of the loop. However, The **console.log(k)** shows that its value is kind of **random**. The loop is not waiting for the previous iteration to finish before **running again**.

I also tried to put the redirect part outside the for loop but it doesn't work either.

**My guess** is that I should use a **callback**, But I have no idea how to do it in this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all your promises in an array and use `Promise.all()`;

Simplified example:

```
let promises = [];
for (let i=0; i<3; i++) {
    promises.push(methodThatReturnsPromise());
}
return Promise.all(promises).then((results) => {
    console.log('This will reliably execute after all promises, results are:', results);
})
```

Note that `results` is an array with results of respective promises, following the order of the promises in the input array.

Comment: It works ( kinda ). Thanks for the help